# Развлекательные услуги

Tags: синтаксис

Правильно ли говорить "pазвлекательные услуги"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно, потому что услуги можно оказывать в любой сфере деятельности, и в частности в развлекательной.

В контексте:

> Вопрос «как отдохнуть и чем себя занять?» у вас просто не возникнет: в
>   ВКС-Кантри большой выбор развлекательных услуг для детей и взрослых.

Развлекательные услуги:

> Популярные ТВ-шоу и передачи, музыкальные клипы, детские,
>   развлекательные и познавательные программы и видеоролики везде, где
>   есть доступ к Wi-Fi или мобильному интернету. Подключите интересующую
>   рубрику и наслаждайтесь просмотром любимых программ!
>
> Активировав подписку, вы получаете доступ к услуге с любого
>   устройства: смартфона, планшета или персонального компьютера.
>
> ---
>
> ...Кроме качественных и недорогих услуг мобильной связи, оператор
>   предлагает информационно-развлекательные услуги. Их задача
>   информировать и развлекать клиентов.

---

> Услуга «Запрет развлекательных услуг» позволяет установить запрет на
>   использование голосовых, SMS и USSD-номеров контент-провайдеров, в том
>   числе на отправку SMS и USSD-запросов на номера услуги «Настроение».

[Индустрия развлечений: понятие и основные категории](http://www.cfin.ru/press/practical/2008-09/03.shtml)

> ...Продукт индустрии развлечений в широком смысле — это впечатление,
>   удовольствие, получаемые посредством потребления продуктов (услуг и
>   товаров), достаточных для удовлетворения потребностей в процессе и в
>   целях развлечения.

Answer (score 2):

**Развлекательные услуги** - вполне возможное сочетание, не хуже "ритуальных услуг" и т. п. Главное, употреблять его в подходящих случаях. **Оказывает** или **предоставляет** такую услугу не артист и не музыкант (за исключением случая прямого найма на частную вечеринку, напр. рок-звезды султаном Брунея или найма "девушки из торта" по личной с ней договорённости), а *посредники*. Именно они организуют людям досуг, *предоставляя* им *возможность "развлечься"*, посетив концерт (удобным способом забронировав билеты), прослушав заказанную запись или поиграв в сетевую игру. По всей видимости, это пока не вполне привычное сочетание стало распространяться по мере появления необходимости отделить одну большую группу услуг (напр. профильные услуги в рамках телефонной компании) от другой, сопутствующей. Это прежде всего *групповое* наименование, в единичной форме оно почти не встречается.

Answer (score 1):

Само сочетание мне не нравится, но бороться бесполезно, это уже закреплено намертво. Так что если вопрос конкретный, связанный с необходимостью редактировать, то править не надо.

А если порассуждать о смысле... Из всех услуг с прилагательным более или менее нормально смотрятся только "информационные услуги" или "медицинские услуги", связанные с понятиями "медицина", "информация" и тому подобное. "Развлекательные" - не из этого ряда. "Развлечение" невозможно предоставить

А все прочие куда более естественно выглядят в виде "услуги портного", "услуги стоматолога", "услуги аниматора" и прочее.

Само же "развлечение" невозможно "предоставить". А услуги именно предоставляют. Это занятие. И это мешает адекватному восприятию.
Видимо, само слово "развлечение" стало восприниматься как нечто отвлеченное, наподобие информации, которую предоставляют.

Comment: Мне кажется, прилагательное может характеризовать не только вид услуг, но и область их приложения. Например, бытовые услуги - услуги, связанные с бытом, развлекательные услуги -  услуги, связанные с развлечениями.

Comment: @М_Г Если не трудно, что конкретно в вашем сообщении относится к моему ответу? Просто не форме сейчас читать между строк, на меня с трех сторон "баллон катят" только на ресурсе. Бытовые  услуги - это услуги, их, например, оказывают. А что такое "оказать развлекательные услуги"?! Можно как-то организовать развлечение, но оказать?! Вон там в другом ответе есть упоминание "ритуальные услуги" - это поинтереснее пожалуй... это вот тот самый шаблон, о котором я говорил. "Ритуал" (как и развлечение) превратился из действия в некий "быт" - условное/отвлеченное  именование всего, что с ним связано..